# WinForm UI Data binding to View Model, How to Cancel Editing Discard Unwanted Changes

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

[image]

My Submit Form is binding to a Submit ViewModel via bindingSource1.

**What I expected:** When editing, I don't want the UI values to be assigned to the ViewModel.
I want the values to be assigned to the ViewModel only after the "Submit" button is hit, and UI values are validated, then I will call `bindingSource.EndEdit();`. Only by then, UI values should be written into ViewModel.

**What I experienced:** I find my understanding to be not true. After I edited a text field, as soon as I lost focus to that textbox or combobox, the change is remembered in such a way that, doesn't matter if I hit "Cancel" or [x] close button. The value is now assigned into the ViewModel in memory when this Form is closed. (Of course, because I didn't hit "Submit", so it didn't go through all the IO logics)

I want bindingSource to discard the unwanted changes when I "Cancel"/[x] close my edit. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default data binding updates the underlying data source on validation event. By default validation event happens when you leave the control. However, both behaviors can be customized.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983250/897326) on how to implement cancellation with data bindings. You would suspend automatic data binding updates, and then force them to be done manually on `Submit`.

As an alternative, you can set `CausesValidation = False` on your controls. Then, have `Cancel` button just close your form, and your `Submit` do something similar to this:

```
control1.CausesValidation = True
control2.CausesValidation = True
control3.CausesValidation = True
Me.ValidateChildren()
control1.CausesValidation = False
control2.CausesValidation = False
control3.CausesValidation = False
```

If you decide to go with the above approach for production use, enumerate through your controls once (for example, inside `Form_Load`), and collect those that are data bound. You can then easily run through them in a loop and set `CausesValidation` to either `True` or `False`. Or have a helper method that does this, to be reused on other forms.

Comment: Thanks Neo, and merry Xmas :)